# Query records from multiple tables and determine which table they came from

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from multiple tables in a way that I can determine which table it came from.  I think I'm close but the following sql doesn't quit work:

```
SELECT name, id
AS player FROM players
WHERE name LIKE '%str%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, id
AS team FROM teams
WHERE name LIKE '%str%'
```

Below are the results that I'm getting (as a php assoc array).  Note that for item 2 the key for the id is player but it should be team.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Some string
        [player] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Some other string 
        [player] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => string
        [player] => 2  // THE KEY HERE SHOULD BE TEAM
    )
)
```

Comment: It seems like you should be doing a join instead for what you're trying to accomplish. Certainly players are on a team?

Comment: That's a good point but the table names I used in my example are not the table names in my database (just used them to simplify the problem) and in my case the tables and data are exclusive. I should have chosen a different name for the table.  Thanks for the note.

Comment: I see, so then there's no way to join the tables. I would go with mureinik's answer then. It's probably what I would have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `union` or `union all` to join several queries, only the column names (or alias) of the first query are taken into account. You can work around this by adding a fake column and with a  hardcorded string for the type.
E.g.:

```
SELECT name, id, 'player' AS type
FROM players
WHERE name LIKE '%str%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, id, 'team' AS type
FROM teams
WHERE name LIKE '%str%'
```

With your sample date, this query would produce the following result:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Some string
        [id] => 1
        [type] => player
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Some other string 
        [id] => 2
        [type] => player
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => string
        [id] => 2
        [type] => team
    )
)
```

And now, you can easily distinguish between players and teams in your result.

Answer (score 1):

From 'tblname' column you can recognize name of table.

```
SELECT name, id AS player,'players' as tblname FROM players WHERE name LIKE '%str%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, id AS team,'teams' as tblname FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '%str%'
```