# MySQL select query from multiple identical tables and determine the table in the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I have multiple tables with identical columns and different data in them and i'm trying to make a single query to pull the data from all those tables and treat them as a single query. I also need to know from which table is the specific result. [I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811492/pdo-select-from-multiple-identical-tables)
 to help me get a query from multiple tables, but when i try

```
$tables=array("loads", "loads_completed");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $table = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`','``',$table).'`';
  $sql[] = "(
    SELECT   *
    FROM  $table
    ORDER BY status
    LIMIT    50
  )";
}
$sql = implode(' UNION ALL ', $sql);
```

i get `Query was empty` even though there is content in both tables.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030874/query-records-from-multiple-tables-and-determine-which-table-they-came-from) is what i found for displaying the result table, but i'm not sure how to form the query with array of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by this way

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $table = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`','``',$table).'`';
  $sql[] = "(
    SELECT   *,'".$table."' AS tableName
    FROM  $table
    ORDER BY status
    LIMIT    50
  )";
}
```

Comment: I get      < Query was empty

Comment: Actually that worked, i had error elsewhere in the code. Thank you.